# Why is there no \dollars in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

Very strange discovery today for a newbie. If I want to type pounds, I could use `\pounds` to get the British Pounds symbol, but apparently, LaTeX does not recognize `\dollars`. (I have to type `\$`).

Is there a reason behind that?

Comment: The symbol for pounds is not in ASCII.

Comment: Is something stopping you from defining `\newcommand\dollars{\$}`? Maybe the creator(s) of LaTeX didn't bother providing such a definition since writing `\$` would seem quicker than writing `\dollars` does?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The reason is good old ASCII code that has a slot for `$`, but no slot for `£`.

Since `$` has a special meaning for TeX, Knuth decided that in order to obtain the “$” glyph one just needed to escape `$`, so to type `\$`.

The pound symbol is available in fonts, but there used to be no straightforward way to input it (remember that when TeX was born there was no Unicode and code pages extending ASCII differed wildly among operating systems). Hence the solution was to define a control sequence for it.

There is no need for `\dollars`: I don't think you believe that typing `\dollars` is more practical than typing `\$`.

Now that we have Unicode and UTF-8 it's much simpler to type `£` instead of `\pounds`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\$100 is good, but £100 is better.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your incredibily detailed answer. Would you mind expanding a bit on typing pound sign directly using UTF-8?

Comment: @jxhyc If you have an up-to-date LaTeX system, just type in `£` and see.

Comment: These days £100 isn't much better than $100.

Comment: @IanThompson It's currently about $23.68 better, which I'd say is quite a bit better.

Comment: $5 is better than nothing. And nothing is better than perfect happiness. Therefore $5 is better than perfect happiness.

Comment: I would argue about it being simpler, unless you either have a British-specific keyboard, or use pounds frequently enough to have memorized the extended key combination.  \pounds is MUCH simpler for most of us.

Comment: Using US-International-Layout AltGr+Shift+4 gives a '£', AltGr+5 gives a '€' (not hard to remember, if you occasionally use either of them)

Comment: @jamesqf Or Compose+L+-: £

Comment: @jamesqf As you said, that depends on the definition of "us".

Comment: @chtz It depends on the keyboard layout and the OS; on my keyboard I have nothing like “AltGr”, of course. I simply get `£` by pressing “Option+3”. And `€` by pressing “Shift-Option-2”.

Comment: @chtz: I'd still have to do a bit of looking to figure out what key(s) on my (standard US, Linux, X) keyboard are set up as AltGr or Compose.  And then there's the question of whether the xterm window I'm writing my LaTeX code in actually knows how to display particular characters.  (From playing with this some time ago, it accepts some, but far from all.)

Comment: @Pharap --- [It's all relative](https://www.macrotrends.net/2549/pound-dollar-exchange-rate-historical-chart).

Comment: @IanThompson 'Much' is relative.

Comment: In Plain TeX you can do `{\it\$}` to get £.  Boringly, LaTeX changes the mapping and `\textit{\$}` just gives $ in italics.

Answer (score 11):

The LaTeX kernel has `\textdollar`, as well as `\textsterling`, `\texteuro`, `\textcent`, `\textyen` and `\textdollaroldstyle` for a dollar sign with two bars.

On older kernels, you might need to include the `fontspec` or `textcomp` packages to use some of these.

Comment: all of textcomp is part of the kernel these days

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, dollars and pounds are on equal footing in ConTeXt:

```
\starttext
\textdollar 100 is good, but \textsterling 100 is better.
\stoptext
```

or an Wolfgang Schuster mentions in the comments, use `\asciimode` and directly enter the symbols:

```
\asciimode
\starttext
$100 is good, but £100 is better.
\stoptext
```

Comment: With `\asciimode` you can write `$100 is good, but £100 is better.` without the need for TeX commands.

Comment: and so is LaTeX, which too has \textdollar and \textsterling  (\pounds is historical)

Answer (score 1):

Is that nobody use `\EyesDollar`? XD

Seriously, there are a few other dollar commands beside `\$` (or `\textdollar`), but one must take into account if  they work also in both math and text mode, if they need a package (that can be lost in a copy and paste, and then find out ...) o more "fun", it is custom macro based in a composed character, instead a simple glyph, that could be "decomposed", or even produce a fatal error, changing something else in the document or using another compiler.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % compile with xelatex !!
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Symbola} % needed for some glyphs !!
\usepackage{geometry}  \usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{tabto}
\TabPositions{5cm,7.5cm,8.5cm,12cm}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\parindent0pt\parskip.8em\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Just for the sake of completeness} 

Symbol \tab Math \tab Text\par
\medskip\par  
\verb.\$(\textdollar)£(\pounds). \tab {\Large$\$(\textdollar)£(\pounds)$} \tab {\Large\$(\textdollar)£(\pounds)} \par
\verb.\mathdollar. \tab  {\Large$\mathdollar$} \tab \vbox to 1.25em {\textcolor{red}{oops! ⛔}} \par
\verb.\textdollaroldstyle. \tab  {\Large$\textdollaroldstyle$} \tab  {\Large\textdollaroldstyle}\par  
\verb.\faDollar. \tab  {\Large$\faDollar$} \tab  {\Large\faDollar}\par
\verb!S+...//! \tab
 {\Large$S\kern-.52em\vbox to .8em{\hbox{/}}\kern-.15em\vbox to .8em{\hbox{/}}$} \tab
{\Large S\kern-.52em\vbox to .8em{\hbox{/}}\kern-.15em\vbox to .8em{\hbox{/}}}\par
\verb!S+ ...||! \tab
 {\Large $S\kern-.42em\vbox to .8em{\hbox{|}}\kern-.1em\vbox to .8em{\hbox{|}}$} 
\tab
 {\Large S\kern-.42em\vbox to .8em{\hbox{|}}\kern-.1em\vbox to .8em{\hbox{|}}} \par


There are also \verb.\bbdollar. of the \href{https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mbboard}{\ttfamily mbboard} package (in CTAN  but not available from \TeX Live nor Mik\TeX\  download managers).


\section*{Just joking: } 
\TabPositions{1cm,4cm}
\tab {\Large\EyesDollar} \tab Tempting dollars (evil snake)\par 
\tab {\Large\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\EyesDollar}} \tab Healing dollars (Aesculapius snake) \par\tab 
{\Large\textcircled{\resizebox{!}{.55em}{\$}} \mbox{\vbox to .61em{\hbox to .5em{\$}}⃝} }  
{\Large\Circled[outer color=gray,inner color=gray!10, fill color=gray!60]{\$}}
\tab Silver dollar coins \par % U+20DD
\tab{\Large\Circled[outer color=black,inner color=orange!30!yellow, fill color=orange!60!brown]{\$}} 
\tab Fiat (fake) copper dollar\par 
\tab {\Large }  \tab Fiat (fake) banknote dollar  \par  % U+1F4B5 
\tab {\Large$\mathds{S}$} \tab Half dollar (50 ¢)\par
\tab {\Large\mbox{\vbox to .6em{\hbox to .5em{\scalebox{.97}{\$}}}⃠}} \tab I am broke (0 \$) % U+20E0


\end{document}
```